# One sample permutation test on skewed data

Tags: skewness, permutation

I have one sample of values, each of them is a z-score from mutually independent z-scored distributions. I aimed at testing that the mean value of the sample is larger than zero. Originally I wanted to test it using one-sample permutation test, however, the z-scored distributions turn out to be skewed, so the sign flipping seems to be invalid. The distributions are skewed in a way, where most of the datapoints are negative but close to zero, while some of the data are positive with higher absolute value.
Which test is appropriate in this situation?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I just want to clarify that I am not performing a test on z-scored distribution, but rather on a sample, where each of the values is a z-score, but from different distributions.

Comment: But you still haven't said what you mean by z-scored. And what do you mean by 'different distributions'? Not sure how to make sense of a test on a dataset that is not a sample from a particular definable distribution, population, or process.

Comment: The z-scores were obtained by the formula you are mentioning (substracting mean and dividing by std). The different distributions correspond to different measurments, where within within each measurment some conditions were shuffled to obtain random distribution and observed value is z-scored in respect to that distribution, This has been done for multiple experiments/measurments  which rendered z-score values constituing the tested sample.

Comment: You give me limited choices how to try to help. Options are (a) I just pick a skewed sample with some negative values and try to illustrate a permutation test for $0$ mean. (b) You give me some data: along a row, commas separating values. (c) You give me an idea how to simulate data that might be enough like yours to be helpful. What is sample size?

Comment: Thank you, would be grateful even for (a). I am meanwhile thinking of how to describe nature of my data in simple and meaningful way. The sample size to perform the test on is 26 values.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the main problem is that z-values come from different, even thought rather similar distributions, thank you for putting this forward. The only thing I know that mean value of each distribution is zero, but not sure if I can use it for any inference regarding the resulting sample. I dont know what to do.

Comment: To state it formally, let N be a natural number. Then we have N samples, each of them consisting of 1000 values. Lets z-score values within each sample. For each of the N samples there is also a value that we call an observation and is tranformed to z-score with respect to N-th sample distribution. We want to test that mean of observations is significantly higher than it would be if we were randomly taking one value from each of the N samples instead.

Comment: It is tempting to basically perform randomization test with randomly taking one value from each of the samples and calculating the mean, however, I want to ensure to test 'group effect' accounting for contribution by individual values, not just very few very large outliers.

Comment: See my answer using option (a). Seemed to have no difficulty with it.

Comment: Thank you! Originally was afraid to do sign flipping around mean permutations, as in the case of skewed distribution I had feeeling it does not nonparametrically model the null hypothesis. Or it is not a problem?

Comment: Regarding permutation tests, here are discussions about 'exchangeability', which you should read. It depends on what the null hypothesis really is. // Another approach is to transform data, something like $y = x^{1/5}$ to get rid of some skewness, then do a test for mean = 0; permutation or maybe even t if transformed data nearly normal. The _medians_ of orig'l and transformed data are the same, but not the means. // Because you have no idea what the actual population is, trying to test whether its mean is $0$ is going to be subject to some discussion.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that in some variation of a problem I have integer values data, again with skewed distribution, most of the values equal to zero and few values positive integers. What variant of permutation can be used here, since the data are strongly asymetric with respect to both mean and median (median equals to zero, but more than half values are equal to zero).

Comment: Maybe a simple sign test would work. How many observations overall> how many negative? and how many positive? For example, if 1000 altogether, 30 negative and 10 positive, then one-sided test rejects $0$ as true location of median. In R, code`pbinom(10,40,.5)` returns P-value $ 0.001110717.$

Answer (score 1):

**Data.** Here is a right skewed sample that has some negative values, but a sample average $A$ somewhat above $0.$

```
set.seed(1234)
n = 200;  x = rexp(n, .1) - 8
a.obs = mean(x); a.obs
[1] 2.045604
stripchart(x, pch="|")
abline(v = mean(x), col="greens")
```

[image]

**Permutation test.** Now we use the sample mean as metric, permute signs of
the $n = 200$ observations, and find the average `a.perm` of the
sign-permuted data. With $10\,000$ such values
we can get a good idea of the permutation distribution sample averages.

The null hypothesis that the mean is $0$
for the distribution from which `x` was randomly sampled
is rejected. The P-value of the test is about $0.0035 < .05 = 5\%.$

```
set.seed(326)
a.prm = replicate(10^4, 
                   mean(sample(c(-1,1),n,rep=T)*x))
mean(abs(a.prm)>=abs(a.obs))
[1] 0.0035   # P-value of permutation test

hist(a.prm, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="Permutation Dist'n")
 abline(v = c(a.obs,-a.obs), lwd=2, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]